# Using LogParser to generate average response time graph

Tags: log-files, logparser

How can I get this graph:

[image]

(from [Speeding up StackExchange](http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/459188139/speeding-up-stackexchange))

It shows what percentage of web requests took longer than N seconds. I have IIS logs and LogParser installed but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can do it with LogParser and Excel:

**Step 1** Create the following query and save it as "Time taken graph.sql":

```
SELECT QUANTIZE(time-taken, 100) AS t, COUNT(*) as count
INTO 'Time-taken-graph.csv'
FROM u_ex*.log GROUP BY t
```

**Step 2** Run the query and export results to CSV file:

```
LogParser.exe file:"Time taken graph.sql"
```

**Step 3** Open CSV file in Excel. I will use Excel 2010 as example.
Let's say your data sits in A1:B401 range:

[image: Initial data]

Put "Time" in D1 cell. Put "Percent" in E1 cell. Fill time in D column with series starting from 0 to 5 with step 0.1:

[image: time series]

**Step 4** Put the following formula into E2 cell (you will need to replace 401 with your value):

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$401,">="&D2*1000,$B$2:$B$401)/SUM($B$2:$B$401)
```

[image: formula]

Copy the formula to all cells in E column that have corresponding time value. Set style to Percent by pressing Ctrl+Shift+%

[image]

**Step 5** Finally, build line graph based on the data in D and C columns:
[image: Graph]

Comment: When doing anything like this I use Perl to read the data (most commonly stored in a database) to create the charts in Excel. A bit of searching should turn up a number of articles on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python program to generate that graph using the logs generated by our load balancer and [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to draw the actual graph.

I went through a couple of iterations before I decided on that graph:

- I started with a scatter plot (response time versus time of day) which is informative in it's own right, good for getting a good feel for the shape and variance of your traffic even if it's not particularly good for communication.
- Then I tried a histogram, which wasn't particularly useful because of the high variance.
- Finally I ended up with this which is based on a histogram, but is cumulative and inverted.

I'd post the code but it is so specific to what I was doing that it isn't going to help anybody. So here's an approximation of the core function:

```
def point(times, cutoff):
    """
        times: sorted list of response times
        0 <= cutoff < 1
    """

    size = int(len(times) * cutoff)
    return (times[cutoff], 1 - cutoff)
```

You then plot the `(x, y)` coordinates as cutoff ranges over `[0,1[` using your favourite plotting library.